# java - Compare two json objects with same keys in different order

Tags: java

Given two json objects

```
String a1 = "{\"a\":[{\"b\":\"1\"}, {\"b\":\"2\"}]}";
String a2 = "{\"a\":[{\"b\":\"2\"}, {\"b\":\"1\"}]}";
```

I'd like to compare them regardless of the order of objects in the array. I'm using `Jackson` but it doesn't work.

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper().configure(
    SerializationFeature.ORDER_MAP_ENTRIES_BY_KEYS, true
);
Map<String, Object> m1 = (Map<String, Object>)(om.readValue(a1, Map.class));
Map<String, Object> m2 = (Map<String, Object>)(om.readValue(a2, Map.class));
System.out.println(m1.equals(m2));
```

Is there any handy way to compare them properly?

Comment: Those are not equal.

Comment: why would you consider those object to be equal?

Comment: My fault. I should rather say comparing them regardless of the order of objects in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Your `om.readValue()` call is returning a `Map<String, List<Map<String, Integer>>>`:

```
Map<String, List<Map<String, Integer>>> m1 = om.readValue(a1, Map.class);
Map<String, List<Map<String, Integer>>> m2 = om.readValue(a2, Map.class);

System.out.println(m1); //{a=[{b=1}, {b=2}]}
System.out.println(m2); //{a=[{b=2}, {b=1}]}
```

The lists `{b=1}, {b=2}` and `{b=2}, {b=1}` are not equal because of their order.
So I converted the list to a HashSet and then ran the comparison:

```
Map<String, HashSet<Map<String, Integer>>> m1Collected = m1.entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> Map.entry(e.getKey(), new HashSet<>(e.getValue())))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

Map<String, HashSet<Map<String, Integer>>> m2Collected = m2.entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> Map.entry(e.getKey(), new HashSet<>(e.getValue())))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

System.out.println(m1Collected.equals(m2Collected)); //prints true
```

You can also use [JSONassert](http://jsonassert.skyscreamer.org/cookbook.html) with strict mode set to false, to compare JSONs ignoring the order.

Comment: but then you are modifying the object before comparing it. It's like saying `"foo" == "ofo"`

Comment: @njzk2 if the OP wanted to compare the ordering, they wouldn't have posted the question